# Deleting unwanted data in incremental imports when using Solr DIH

Tags: search, solr

I have a data to be indexed. The table has a column called 'state' which could be 'published' 'drafted' OR 'deleted'. Now I only index the data which has a state as 'published'. If a data in database is updated to 'deleted' from 'published' how do I deleted this data from my Solr index when using incremental imports.

The default behaviour of Solr will be to update the state of the data element to 'deleted' from 'published' which is not desired, rather i want to delete it from the solr index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the deletedPkQuery attribute in your dataConfig with the wanted sql statement, e.g.

```
deletedPkQuery="select ID from table where state = 'deleted'"
```

Does it work for you?
Source http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler
Here is a good tutorial for this: http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/03/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-removing-data-from-index/